# How do I resolve being unable to ping my domain?

Tags: networking, dns, ping

I have a normal .com domain that is tied to a VPS and am unable to ping it using my local machine. I've tried pinging both the domain name and IP address. All packets are lost for both. I am able to ping other domains without a problem. When I ssh'd into the server and pinged the domain name from there, it worked. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: You or your VPS provider have a firewall blocking ping (ICMP echo-request)?

Comment: @mtak I can ping other domains from my local. The VPS has no firewall that is blocking pings. Also, I am able to use it to ping other domains.

Comment: @mtak, sorry, you are correct. I didn't set up (install) any firewall software on the VPS. However, on closer inspection (playing around with the settings on my provider's control panel) I see that there is a "provider level" firewall that only allowed comms on a couple of ports. The others are blocked, so this brings me closer to resolving the issue. I have now enabled the ports I need and will report back.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion by @mtak, it turns out that my VPS provider has a firewall that was blocking my pings. I have now resolved this issue.